# Как изменить вложенные элементы Json на Java?

Tags: java, json

У меня есть Json строка

```
String jsonStr = "{\"id\": \"11111111\",\"amount\": 10000,\"operation\": {\"id\": \"222222222\"," +
            "\"status\": \"SUCCESS\", \"access\": {\"user\": \"Alexa\",\"password\":\"33333333\" }}}";
```

Мне нужно изменить все элементы id на другое значение. Я попробовал вот так и сяк, но не получается:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
jsonObject.remove("id");
jsonObject.put("id", "000000");
```

Результат:

```
{"amount":10000,"operation":{"id":"222222222","status":"SUCCESS","access":{"user":"Alexa","password":"33333333"}},"id":"000000"}
```

В результате изменяется только первый элемент id, и то оно записывается в конец строки.
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было поменять все элементы id?

Comment: В конец или в начало - не имеет значения. 

И эти элементы id на разных уровнях, один на верхнем, а другой входит в значение ключа "operation". Поэтому и удалять/добавлять его надо указав полный "путь".

Comment: @Эникейщик Но мне не известно именно в каком порядке получу Json строку

Comment: Еще раз: порядок не имеет значения. Если вам нужно заменить в красной сумке одну книгу на другую, то неважно, стоит красная сумка слева от синей, справа или перед ней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя библиотеку [`FasterXML Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), можно прочитать заданную JSON-строку в `ObjectNode` так как он позволяет менять значения при помощи методов `put`, `set`, `replace` и др., при этом может создаваться новое поле, если не будет найдено существующее

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonStr);

root.put("id", 324);
root.set("id2", new TextNode("456"));

System.out.println("id:" + root.get("id"));
System.out.println("id2:" + root.get("id2"));

root.put("id", 324);

System.out.println("id:" + root.get("id"));

((ObjectNode) root.get("operation")).put("id", "abcd-ef01-23456789");

System.out.println("op.id:" + root.get("operation").get("id"));
```

Вывод:

```
id:324                           // заменили на int
id2:"456"                        // создали новое поле
op.id:"abcd-ef01-23456789"       // заменили на другое строковое значение
```

---

Также можно реализовать рекурсивную функцию для поиска всех полей и присваивания им нового значения:

```java
static void updateField(ObjectNode node, String fieldName, String newValue) {
    if (node.has(fieldName)) // проверить наличие поля в текущем объекте
        node.put(fieldName, newValue);

    // проверить вложенные поля
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> nested = it.next();
        if (nested.getValue().isObject()) {
            updateField((ObjectNode) nested.getValue(), fieldName, newValue);
        }
    }
}

// вызов:
updateField(root, "id", "333");
System.out.println("id:" + root.get("id"));
System.out.println("op.id:" + root.get("operation").get("id"));
```

Вывод:

```java
id:"333"
op.id:"333"
```

---

Альтернативный "читерский" вариант -- использовать регулярные выражения и заменять пары `"поле": "значение"` по совпадению шаблона безо всякого разбора JSON при помощи методов `String::replaceAll / String::replaceFirst`

```
System.out.println(jsonStr.replaceAll("(\"id\"\\s*:\\s*)\"([^\"]*)\"", "$1\"5555\""));
System.out.println(jsonStr.replaceFirst("(\"id\"\\s*:\\s*)\"([^\"]*)\"", "$1\"XYZ\""));
```

Результат:

```
{"id": "5555","amount": 10000,"operation": {"id": "5555","status": "SUCCESS", "access": {"user": "Alexa","password":"33333333" }}}
{"id": "XYZ","amount": 10000,"operation": {"id": "222222222","status": "SUCCESS", "access": {"user": "Alexa","password":"33333333" }}}
```

Comment: Рекурсия помогла, благодарю